# Add dots on scroll images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my scroll images section and I want to improve it that there will be dots which will show on what position you are and how many images the scroll section have. I want the dots under the images and they will change their color on other positions. Can someone help me with that, how to do it? I do not know how to do it so if someone can help me with this i will be very glad.

Thank you.

```
<section class="scroll-images">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
    <div class="carousel">
      <img src="#" alt="" draggable="false">
      <img src="#" alt="" draggable="false">
      <img src="#" alt="" draggable="false">
      <img src="#" alt="" draggable="false">
      <img src="#" alt="" draggable="false">
      <img src="#" alt="" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  caret-color: #ffb038;
}

.scroll-images {
  display: flex;
  padding: 80px 35px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1500px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper i {
  top: 50%;
  background: #ffb038;
  color: #fff;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 46px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.wrapper i:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper i:first-child {
  left: -23px;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper i:last-child {
  right: -23px;
}

.wrapper .carousel {
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel.dragging {
  cursor: grab;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}

.carousel.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.carousel img {
  height: 340px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-left: 14px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.carousel img:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked how other people achieve this? For example https://codepen.io/Snip3r/pen/GxybbN (not mine)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Carousel active dots and left-right buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861385/javascript-carousel-active-dots-and-left-right-buttons)